# Laravel Eloquent ORM Factory: Will afterMaking be called before afterCreating when I create a model with a factory;

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

According to Laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing) you can specify the triggers `afterMaking` and `afterCreating`. But I cannot figure out when these triggers are being called and in what sequence

So I have this scenario:

```
$myModel=factory(MyModel::class)->create();
```

With the following factory:

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use App\Model\MyModel

$factory->define(MyModel::class,function(Faker $faker){

return [
   'sum'=>10
];
});

$factory->afterCreating(MyModel::class,function(MyModel $model, Faker $faker){

  $model->sum=30;
  $model->save();
});


$factory->afterCreating(MyModel::class,function(MyModel $model, Faker $faker){

  $model->sum=30;
  $model->save();
});

$factory->afterMaking(MyModel::class, function(MyModel $model, Faker $faker){
   $model->sum=40;
});
```

So which of the following assumptions are correct?

1. A `MyModel` instance is created first, then `afterMaking` closure is called, then the Object is writen into the Db and finally `afterCreating` is called.
2. A `MyModel` instance is created first, en the Object is writen into the Db and finally `afterCreating` closure is called.
3. A `MyModel` instance is created first then `afterCreating` closure is called and then the Object is written into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `create` method calls `make` internally. `make` will call `callAfterMaking` after it creates the instance(s). `create` will then call `callAfterCreating` after it stores the record(s).

So, option 1.

Comment: So the correct is the `A MyModel instance is created first, then afterMaking closure is called, then the Object is writen into the Db and finally afterCreating is called.` right?